# Word VBA Documents.Open deleting files in folder when falsely passing that folder's path instead of file path

Tags: vba, ms-word

I encountered the following issue:
When accidentally passing a folder path to the Documents.Open function in VBA Word I get the runtime error 5174 as one would expect.
However all files with names **that begin with an underscore** get deleted in that moment from that folder.

To replicate:

Assume folder C:/Test/

In said folder have two files:

test.txt

_test.txt

In Word VBA execute the command:

```
Documents.Open("C:/Test/")
```

(As part of a subroutine or in the immediate window.)

Result: Runtime Error 5174 and _test.txt is now missing.

Note: Passing a nonexisting file like "C:/Test/abc.txt" or a wrong folder path like "C:/Test" (without the last slash) will not have this effect and won't cause the runtime error.

I have only tested this on one system on a network drive under windows 10 with Microsoft Professional Plus 2019. It's entirely possible that it's an issue with the file system. Does anyone have any suggestions as to why is this happening? I now included the workaround to check if I'm passing a folder, but it's still unnerving.

Comment: Just reporting that I couldn't reproduce this: I got the error but my "_test.txt" is still here. (I am running Microsoft 356)

Comment: @SuperSymmetry thanks for clearing that up, I suspected that might be the case. I wonder what in the file system is causing this.

Comment: Do you get the same results when you are doing that manually?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev how would I open a folder in word manually? Afaik the file picker dialog doesn't allow for opening folders. Why would it, you'd just get an error.

Comment: What is your end goal?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev finding a possible reason as to what's wrong with the file system that the deletion occurs. I've already circumvented the problem in my code, but I can't trust On Error statements when the error still deletes files.

Answer (score 0):

The [Documents.Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.documents.open) method opens the specified document and adds it to the Documents collection. It is designed to take the file path, not a folder. If you want to allow users to pick file(s) you may consider using the file open dialog. The [FileOpenDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.filedialog) triggered by your code which opens a folder for picking files allows specifying file formats that should be supported and visible via the dialog window.

```
Set dlgSaveAs = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
dlgSaveAs.Filter = "Text Files (.txt)|*.txt|Word Documents (.docx)|*.docx|Word Template (.dotx)|*.dotx|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
dlgSaveAs.ValidateNames = true
Res = dlgSaveAs.Show
```

Comment: As I specified in the first line of my question I don't expect the Documents.Open method to be able to open folders. This question is about the deleting of files that occurs when I 
try to do that in error.